# Since updating to Xcode 8.3.2 from 8.2, our UI tests fail as UItableView no longer responds to swipeUp() or swipeDown()

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I've some UI tests which have been working for the past year, and they run every night and we've a monitor set up so we can see when they fail, and they've been fine for months and months.

This morning we updated our machines to Xcode 8.3.2 and our build server to 8.3.2 from 8.2, and now the UI tests no longer pass.

I have a tableView with 12 cells in it, and the first 6 are visible, but I want to press the last cell, so I call swipeUp() to scroll the tableView. Usually, the tableView will scroll for a second or two and the cell I want becomes visible and I'm able to assert that it exists and call tap() on it.

Now however, when watching the UI tests run, when the swipeUp() method is called, it no longer scrolls for very long. It seems to scroll only a few millimetres and then it stops, meaning the assertion fails and we can't tap the cell so all of our UI tests fail.

I've searched online about this, and can't find much information except for [this small snippet](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/75705) which seems to be having the same problem I am.

I have tried to remove the swipeUp() call as suggested but this doesn't seem to fix the issue, and we have tested across several Xcode installations and laptops to the same effect.

Just looking for some advice, and am wondering if anyone else has seen this issue?

Comment: Can you please file a radar for this? With output from both running with 8.3.2 and 8.2, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

There are several possible solutions for this problem.

1. `tap()` method. `XCTestCase` can automatically scroll to given element and tap on it when you use `tap()` method.

   ```swift
   let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "label == %@", "12")
   let cell = table.cells.containing(predicate).element
   cell.tap()
   ```
2. Instead of using `swipeUp()` method you can use `XCUICoordinate.press(forDuration:thenDragTo:)`. This on is a little bit tricky because you have to work on `XCUICoordinate` object.

   Example usage of swiping from the bottom to the top:

   ```swift
   let bottom = table.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.5, dy: 0.9))
   let top = table.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.5, dy: 0.1))

   bottom.press(forDuration: 0.1, thenDragTo: top)
   ```

   Please note values `0.9` and `0.1`.

   - If you use `1.0` as the bottom value you will open **Control Center**.
   - If you implement "swipeDown" using above method and use `0.0` as top point you will open **Notification Center**.
3. If more than one swipe is required you can use `while` loop (or similar) to scroll up until the cell will be visible:

   ```swift
   let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "label == %@", "12")
   let cell = table.cells.containing(predicate).element
   while !cell.isHittable {
       table.swipeUp()
   }
   ```

   Of course, some other break condition would be required ;)
4. You can use [AutoMate](https://github.com/PGSSoft/AutoMate) library which has helper methods for swiping, like: `swipe(to:)`.

   ```swift
   let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "label == %@", "12")
   let cell = table.cells.containing(predicate).element
   table.swipe(to: scrollPage.topButton)
   ```

   In addition, this library can handle situations where a keyboard is visible, handle different device orientation ([rdar://31529903](https://openradar.appspot.com/31529903), [gist](https://gist.github.com/glebon/9b2bc64bfce0dd4299c522df16866822)) and much more.

Comment: Any thoughts why this happened in 8.3.2? I guess that's still a mystery. Anyhow for `label == 12` how does this work? does 12 simply translate to rowNumber? How would go for section 3, row 5?

Comment: Ah, sorry for that. I had an example app where each cell has a label with an own unique number as text. In your project, you have to find something unique for the cell. For example, it can ba a text in the label. Also, you can get 12th cell from table view using `table.cells.element(boundBy:12)`. With section, there is always a problem. I suggest using predicate which will find cell you want. If you try AutoMate you can use `let cell = tableView.cells.element(containingLabels: ["name": "John"])`. This code will find a cell containing any element with identifier `name` and label `John`.